# Simple if-statement that checks if line is in a file

Tags: bash, login, sed

I am trying to create a very simple login console for a script that I have, this is just for fun to see if it works.

Basically what I thought would be possible is this.

I will read in the file `$password_file` and the file `$username_file` if there is a certain pattern. Let's say I put in both files "bryan" on the first line (or whatever line). Now I want to put this piece of code before the script continues to its basic functions.

```
echo "Welcome"
echo "Ur username is:"
read username
echo "Ur password is:"
read password
if sed -n "/$username/" $username_file; then
    if sed -n "/$password" $password_file; then

else
    exit;
    fi
fi
```

I think I am doing something wrong here, because I am getting an error that there is an unexpected token near the `else`.

So basically I just want the if-statement to first read `$username_file`, then if the pattern `bryan` is in that file, I want it to read the `$password_file`, after that I want the script to continue to go to a certain line in the script on which the normal script that I wrote starts.

I hope I explained it right, so that you can understand me.

(I can also expand this little script by adding something like, if username or password is not in that file echo "not found, script will reload try again".)

Comment: I don't understand this part: `after that I want the script to continue to go to a certain line in the script on which the normal script that I wrote starts.` Can you please clarify what you want this script to do if the username and password are both found?

Comment: Of course, reading your password in from a plaintext, local file, from a plaintext, local, readable shell script, is not going to stop *anybody*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that bash is interpreting it as `then; else`; put a `:` in that line.

If each line is only composed of what you're looking for, you can also use `fgrep -x`:

```
echo "Welcome"
echo "Username:"
read username
echo "Password:"
read password
if ! (fgrep -qx "$username" $username_file && fgrep -qx "$password" $password_file); then
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here:

- There are no commands in the `then` portion of your inner `if` statement, which is causing the error you see.  You could solve this by either using the placeholder pseudocommand `:` in the `then` portion, or by negating the test and leaving out the `else` section.
- The `sed` command is also invalid, and it's the wrong tool for the job anyway.  To search a file for a particular line, `grep` is generally the command of choice.  In this case, `grep -Fx` to do a plaintext (`-F`) whole-line (`-x`) match is probably best.
- The if ... if ... else logic is off, also.  I presume you want to exit if either the username or password isn't found, but (as written) the `else` clause only runs if the username *was* found, *and* the password wasn't.  To fix this, use something like this:

  ```
  if ! grep -Fxq "$username" "$username_file" || ! grep -Fxq "$password" "$password_file"; then
      echo "Invalid login"
      exit 1
  fi
  ```

  Or maybe:

  ```
  if ! grep -Fxq "$username" "$username_file"; then
      echo "User $username not found"
      exit 1
  elif ! grep -Fxq "$password" "$password_file"; then
      echo "Incorrect password"
      exit 1
  fi
  ```
- Actually, that logic is still wrong; all it checks is that the username and password exist in their respective files, not that they go together.  I could type in my password and someone else's username, and it'd let me in.  You need to make sure the username and password go together, probably by putting them both in the same file and searching for both at once:

  ```
  if ! grep -Fxq "$username:$password" "$user_file" ; then
      echo "Invalid login"
      exit 1
  fi
  ```
- Finally, storing passwords (even in a file only root can read) is a really bad idea -- hash the password and store the hash instead.  Actually, for best security you should use a salted hash, which complicates searching -- you have to find the user entry, figure out the salt that was used with its password, hash what the user typed with the same salt, and compare that with what's in the file.  This in turn means that `grep -Fx` won't work anymore, we need to use `grep` in a mode that does pattern matching and be careful to avoid pattern metacharacters in the username...

Here's a quick stab at this, assuming you have openssl available:

```
echo "Welcome"
read -p "Ur username is: " username
if [[ "$username" =~ "[][(){}*.?+|^\$]" ]]; then
    echo "Illegal character in username"
    exit 1
fi

# Find the user's record in the file
user_record="$(grep "^$username:" "$user_file")"
if [[ -z "$user_record" ]]; then
    echo "User $username not found"
    exit 1
fi
# Parse out the user's hashed password and salt
recordedhash="${user_record#*:}"
if [[ "$recordedhash" != '$1$'* ]]; then
    echo "Invalid user record for $username"
    exit 1
fi
salt="${recordedhash#\$1\$}"
salt="${salt%\$*}"

read -p "Ur password is: " -s password
echo
if [[ "$(printf "%s" "$password" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin -salt "$salt")" != "$recordedhash" ]]; then
    echo "Incorrect password"
    exit 1
fi
```

To create entries in the user file, use something like this:

```
read -p "Ur username is: " username
if [[ "$username" =~ "[][(){}*.?+|^\$]" ]]; then
    echo "Illegal character in username"
    exit 1
fi
read -p "Ur password is: " -s password
echo
hashedpw="$(printf "%s" "$password" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin)"
user_record="$username:$hashedpw"
# Then do something to add $user_record to the file, or replace the existing record if there is one
```

I make no promises that the above is bug-free; I've just done some very basic tests on it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [X Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Why do you want to do this? As @Gordon Davisson's excellent answer shows, this is more difficult than you think. Not only are there security issues to think about, unix passwords are not all stored in /etc/passwd. So either you'll have to redo a lot of what [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) already does.

A quick idea, maybe you want to do something like

PASSED=$(su $USER -c "echo LOGIN")

If the su fails, then they don't have the password. Then PASSED will be blank. By using su, you'll go through all the normal password routines, using pam if needed, and you won't need to maintain anything.

Comment: Security is not really an required thing in what I want to do. This is just something that I can do for extra credit at school. I will look @Gordon Davisson's answer this afternoon. Thanks alot guys for your help. I did notice that there was nothing in the second if to do if it is true.